# How can I create a “Open with” list as in Explore in my own application

Tags: c#, registry, open-with

In my application the user can select reference to file, for example a image file. I would like to make button with a arrow that opens a list with the programs installed on the system witch can open this file type.

I know that I can get the program names from the registry "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts", but how can I filter the entries out that have no meaning - "DllHost.exe, miaui.exe, etc."
And how can I open the file with program that the user choose?

[image]

@ Lars Tech If I look in registry "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\" and then "OpenWithList" for the  extension ".jpg" I see more entries that if if rigt click on jpg file and choose Open With ( see my first images) and I only want those.
And yes there is program's entries that I properly self have added, but that have no meaning to a jpg file. And Windows can filter them out so will I.
[image]

Comment: Why not just host the standard context menu?

Comment: Could work - I think, but how do I implement that?

Comment: [Start here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/20/231739.aspx) and work through the 11-part series.

Comment: How do you define "entries that have no meaning"?  At some point, you (or the user) must have selected those files to open that file type.

Comment: @ Raymond Chen - Sorry this C++ stuff goes beyond my capacity.

Comment: @RaymondChen - the link is dead

Comment: @SimonMourier Fortunately [still in the Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20110317020339/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/20/231739.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen - once we know the title we can get to the "reborn" version https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040920-00/?p=37823 but inner links are still dead. It's a pity your blog has been so broken apart over the years... it has info nowhere else to be found (not even mentioning the official doc). Just saying...

Comment: @SimonMourier That's why I use the Internet Archive links. The inner links also work there. But you can translate from old to new: blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/yyyy/mm/dd/#### becomes devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnetwhing/yyyy/mm/dd -- I fix intrablog links when I can, but there are thousands of articles and only one me. I vaguely recall that the migration team tells me that they can create case-by-case redirects if you ask for them via the Feedback link. But alas there is no bulk redirector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this [article](http://unlockforus.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-remove-invalid-open-with-menu.html) to validate and find out which of them are applicable and valid in your application

Comment: Thanks Jan Its show me that it's more complex than I had hoped. For now the feature is put back in the backlog. But thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

If running on Vista or better, you can use 
'SHOpenWithDialog' 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762234(v=vs.85).aspx
- it's quite straightforward...
Jens